# Using "for i in" for mv recursively

Tags: bash, for-loop, recursion, character, mv

Newbie in bash here(for the most part)...

I successfully wrote a command to remove the character "-" and all other characters thereafter on a single folder:

```
for i in *-*; do mv $i ${i/-*/}; done;
```

This changes all files like "abcf-D.pdf" to "abcf.pdf", thus removing the revision name for drawings from filenames.

My goal is to do this recursively, our pdf files are all on a specific directory on the file server, contained in subfolders and subfolders inside subfolders....

Can this be done from a single command line? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
find . -type f -iname '*-*' -exec rename -v 's/-.*(\.[^.]+)$/$1/' {} \;
```

Assuming you only want to rename files (otherwise remove `-type f`).

---

**Edit**

Reread the question and realised I had gotten the task wrong, so I've edited the regex.

Comment: Hmm, I do not have rename on the Mac, will look for home-brew vs. thanks

Comment: The accepted answer to the question of which yours is a duplicate contains a version without `rename`. But then again I recommend installing it since it's a great tool.

Comment: That answer is a bit above my pay grade.. I am not sure how to replace the "foo" for anything like "foo and all other characters before the extension"

Comment: @Dotpage Basically use the command in your question, but with `$1` instead of `$i`.

Comment: Found a port to replace rename: file-nename. Final code: find . -type f -iname '*-*' -exec file-rename -v 's/-//g' {} \;